# error with slug in django - template it show all posts data in each post

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Error with a slug in Django - template it shows all posts data in each post
when I create a new post and write my data it shows all data from other posts why is that?
and how I can fix it?

```
also how I can add an auto-generation slug?
```

models.py :

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Android(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",help_text="this is title for slug not post!")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    app_contect = models.CharField(max_length=240,default="")
    app_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    post_tag = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",choices = BLOG_SECTION_CHOICES)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True,uniqe=True) # new
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('android_posts', kwargs={'slug': self.slug}) # new


    def get_image(self):
        if self.app_image and hasattr(self.app_image, 'url'):
            return self.app_image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date',)
```

views.py :

```
def android_posts(request,slug):
    android_posts = Android.objects.all()
    context = {'android_posts':android_posts}
    return render(request,'android/android_problems_fix.html', { 'android_posts': android_posts })
```

html page :

```
 {% for android in android_posts %}
 <h1 id="font_control_for_header_in_all_pages">{{android.name}}</h1>
 <hr>
 <p id="font_control_for_all_pages">{{android.app_contect}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

url :

```
path('Android/<slug:slug>', views.android_posts, name='android_posts'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To autogenerate your slug (and only do it on initial save, so that it remains consistent), add the generation to your model `save` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(<Model>, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.pk:
        self.slug = <slugify code here>
```

As for your view/Template, you are specifically selecting all posts using:

```
android_posts = Android.objects.all()
```

Passing them to the template, then looping over them with the `for` loop to display them all.

Instead of this, select only a single object with:

```
android_post = Android.object.get(pk=<pk value>)
```

---

Edit after you added your urls.py:

You can get the unique object for a slug with:

```
android_post = get_object_or_404(Android, slug=slug)
```

The use of `get_object_or_404` will also handle the case where that record doesn't exist.

---

You haven't posted your `urls.py`, so not sure how you're linking to this view, but if it includes the slug in the url, you will be able to get this in the view. My guess is you're not accessing via slug in the url, but via the `id` field.

Personally, when I slugify some text, I always include the `id` - it is a better way of ensuring uniqueness. By specifying `unique=True` on your non-pk slug field, you are likely restricting the titles people can use (2 people couldn't use the same title then!)

To give you an example, this is how I am doing it on one of my models:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id or not self.slug:
        super(Android, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = slugify(f"{self.title} {str(self.id)}")
    super(Android, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This slug will always be unique because it includes `id` - and 2 people could have a record with the same `title` value without the system objecting.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222278/discussion-on-answer-by-urbanespaceman-error-with-slug-in-django-template-it-s).